# What is a good loop probe to use for non contact measurements at 13.56MHz?

Tags: rf, inductance, nfc, vna

I have a receiving antenna (9 turn spiral, 1cm in diameter) that I would like to measure (inductance) wirelessly at 13.56MHz. While looking through application notes from ST and NXP semiconductors, I found that a loop probe can be used to perform a non contact measurement using a VNA. However, I couldn't find any details on what probe (name, part id or even dimensions) specifically would work for this kind of measurement. On googling, I could only find probes ranging from 30MHz to 3GHz.

Could anyone suggest a loop probe to use? Or even the dimensions of a loop that I can wind myself and connect to a coax as a last resort?

Comment: Not asked, but having a vector network analyzer is not so common. I would make an identical copy of the antenna and measure the transfer function between them. That's a purest possible measurement, it contains nothing of the loop probe. The properties of one antenna can be reasoned with the circuit theory.  At 13,56MHz that small antenna cannot have remarkable far field. The environment unfortunately affects, but you could see the effect.

Comment: We have access to a VNA in the lab so that's not an issue. Making any wired connections to either of the copies would be more involved than doing a wireless measurement due to the fabrication process involved. Thank you for the suggestion though!

Comment: Parallel the coil with different values of C until you get a resonance peak. Given a known capacitance and resonant freq you can resolve L. You could probably determine the L from the VNA, but my VNA fu is not strong!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The requirements for such a loop probe for your application are not that high. As the document from ST states:

> Loop probe can come from the market, or be a self-made single turn loop made with a coaxial connector and a copper wire twisted at the end.

You hook the loop up to your VNA and measure S11. Now you hold the loop probe over your antenna. Where there is a downward peak at S11 is the resonance frequency of the antenna. This method can be used to tune the antenna for the right frequency. But note that the resonant frequencey changes with for example a reader nearby. Therefore you have to tune the antenna for a lower frequncy. I've done this several times and always aimed for 13MHz.

Now back to your loop probe. I used a calibration coil that complies to ISO 10373-6 (just google it). This is a 72mm x 42mm one turn coil with 500µm track width on a FR4 substrate. This is in my eyes a cheap but very good option. But you can also try it first with a coaxial connector and a copper wire twisted at the end.

If you not only want to tune the antenna but also measure its inductance, you can do it by calculating it. Just measure the the resonant frequency of the antenna once and than add some capacitance (somewhat between 10pF - 50pF) in parallel an measure again. Now you have the following:

[image]

You know everything except L and C, which you can calculate. If you want a more precise value, you can do more measurements with different C_p and do a curve fitting.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Yes, that was the plan once I was able to find the appropriate coil to use with the VNA. The ISO 10373-6 should be a good starting point. I was able to find a calibration coil from Comprion online, but it is a little scanty on details. Would you mind sharing the name of the company you got yours from?

Comment: ISO 10373-6 describes two calibration coils. If the Comprion complies to ISO 10373-6 then there is no need for more details since its precisely defined. The one used by us is somewhat self made. We did the layout ourselves (according to specification) and then had the circuit board manufactured.

Comment: Thank you the clarification! Will try and give this a shot. The IC manufacturers (NXP) got back suggesting the same approach.

Comment: did you have to perform any impedance matching with the PCB you got manufactured?

Comment: No, i did not perform any impedance matching. You can do it but it is not necessary. Without matching the overall reflection will be higher but there will be still a clearly recognizable peak at the resonant frequency.